# ElasticSearch + AngularJS Results not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, elasticsearch

I have a problem with displaying data returned by elasticsearch client using AngularJS. 
I have the following code in my html body:

```
<div ng-app="elasticApp" ng-controller="elasticCtrl" class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-repeat="x in hits">
    {{ hits._id }}
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following AngularJS part:

```
var elasticApp = angular.module('elasticApp', ['elasticsearch']);

elasticApp.controller('elasticCtrl', function ($scope, esFactory) {
  var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
  });

  client.search({       
    index: 'riverindex',
    type: 'river',
    body: {
      query: {
        "match_all" : { } 
      }
    }
  }).then(function (resp) {
    $scope.hits = resp.hits.hits;
    console.log($scope.hits);
  }, function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
  });
});
```

I am trying to display results returned by the elasticsearch client. 
In the console, I can see that the JSON data was returned correctly:

```
TRACE: 2015-11-29T19:00:09Z

-> POST http://localhost:9200/riverindex/river/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

<- 200
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
   "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "riverindex",
        "_type": "river",
        "_id": "563e18e6d5603e015ca34165",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "test": "test",
          "_id": "563e18e6d5603e015ca34165"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I can't see results on my web page.

The following is the result of `console.log($scope.hits)`:

[image: http://www.fotosik.pl/zdjecie/048b598e2183e9f2]

I'm new to AngularJS, so if you have idea why it is not working, please try to explain as simple as you can.

Comment: Does the above log from console.log($scope.hits); or just showing the request/ response ?

Comment: The above log comes from console.log($scope.hits);

Comment: why console.log($scope.hits); shows the full response , it should only shows whatever inside the 'hits', try console.log($scope.hits.hits)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated my main post in this topic. I attached the printscreen with log from console.log($scope.hits);. The JSON in first post is the response from elasticsearch. console.log($scope.hits.hits) shows error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your view should be

```
<div ng-app="elasticApp" ng-controller="elasticCtrl" class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-repeat="x in hits">
    {{ x._id }} <---- here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, but it still won't work :/ No idea why

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found simple solution, but probably this is not really elegant one.

In angular part:

```
client.search({     
      index: 'riverindex',
      type: 'river',
      body: {
        query: {
                "match_all" : { } 
           }
      }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.hits = resp.hits.hits;

        $scope.$apply(function () {     
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });
```